# Route not found after updating from Laravel 5.7 to 6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my application to laravel 6, but unfortunately, I can't make my routs work again. The current configuration gives me Page Not Found.

Here how it was working before:

```
// generating a link

$content['fan_prize_url'] = route('claim.prize', ['id' => $content['prize_id'], 'u' => $recipient->guid]);
```

```
// web.php

    Route::get('claim/{contest_prize}', [
        'as' => 'claim.prize',
        'uses' => 'PrizeController@claimPrize',
    ]);
```

```
// PrizeController.php

public function claimPrize(ContestPrize $contest_prize, Request $request)
    {

        if ($contest_prize->contest->is_draft && ! \Auth::check()) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

Before the update the link was looking like this:
https://my.app/claim/14?u=be94df30-16aa-11ea-a5de-2bf3d15638e4

After the update 
https://my.app/claim/claim?id=14&u=be94df30-16aa-11ea-a5de-2bf3d15638e4

When I changed the web.php to be like this

```
Route::get('claim', [
        'as' => 'claim.prize',
        'uses' => 'PrizeController@claimPrize',
    ]);
```

it gave me trying to get property of non-object.

What am I missing? I just went through laravel 6 route generations but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: *it gave me trying to get property of non-object.* What did? Can you post the exact message with corresponding code?

Comment: @Loek sure, sorry. The error says 
'Trying to get property 'is_draft' of non-object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone would get stuck as well, in Laravel 6, apparently, there is a new way of passing values and objects. I had to change

```
$content['fan_prize_url'] = route('claim.prize', ['id' => $content['prize_id'], 'u' => $recipient->guid]);
```

to

```
$content['fan_prize_url'] = route('claim.prize', [$content['prize_id'], 'u' => $recipient->guid]);
```

passing object itself instead of the string and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 6+ made the name of Route parameters for the route() function more strict, the parameter name has to match the name it's given in the the route. Leave the rest as is and try changing the route link generation to the following

```
$content['fan_prize_url'] = route('claim.prize', ['contest_prize' => $content['prize_id'], 'u' => $recipient->guid]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried to change the route generation as you said and also change web.php to
` . Route::get('claim/{id}' `
with the old route generation, but still have the Not Found. 
This is how the link looks like:
(http://127.0.0.1:8000/claim?contest_prize=37&u=eea871c0-0fa1-11ea-9830-eb31933ed684)
The id is valid, the guid is valid.